# How to change div styles after showing/hiding with slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using .slideToggle() to show and hide some divs on my portfolio page. When the divs are shown, I want to apply a box-shadow and background that makes it look like they're sitting on a tray.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/bb6DK/) a jsFiddle that shows what I'm trying to do. It works perfectly there, but for some reason the same code isn't working on [my site](http://andtheniwalkedsomemore.com/design.html). The box-shadow appears for a moment when I click to show the div but quickly disappears when the slideToggle animation is complete. Any idea why? I feel like there must be a style somewhere that's overriding the box-shadow but I can't figure out what it may be.

Here's the Jquery code:

```
$('.portfolioToggle').click(function(e) {
    var toggle = $(this),
        divId = toggle.attr('href');

    $(divId).slideToggle('slow');
    $(divId).toggleClass('portfolioSectionVisible', $(this).is(":visible"));

    var toggleState = toggle.text() == "-" ? "+" : "-"; //change icon
    toggle.hide().text(toggleState).fadeIn("fast");

    e.preventDefault();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.portfolioSection{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:-90%;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:21px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    _display:inline;
    _overflow:hidden;
    _overflow-y:visible;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    margin-bottom:2.25em;
    margin-top:1.5em;
    text-shadow:0 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.9)}

.portfolioSectionVisible{
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #888;
    box-shadow:inner 0 0 5px #888}
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing a ';' on the last property of each class may mean the browser is mis-reading the CSS

```
box-shadow:inner 0 0 5px #888}
```

Change to:

```
box-shadow:inner 0 0 5px #888;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well seems you need to insert a clear div after the last `portfolioItem`. I tried following in  chrome and it is working on your site as well:

```
$("<div/>").css({'clear':'both','height':'1px !important','width':'99%'})
    .insertAfter($("#portfolioContainer1").find(".portfolioItem3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem on your page is that your individual portfolio items are floated left, and their parent container `.portfolioItemContainer` is not expanding vertically to contain them.

One way to solve the problem is by inserting an empty div below the floated divs, and setting it to `clear: both`. But that is not a good solution because you must insert extraneous markup.

Instead, apply a clearfix technique to the parent container to solve the problem. Here is a nice one:

```
.portfolioItemContainer:before,
.portfolioItemContainer:after {
    content: " "; 
    display: table; 
}

.portfolioItemContainer:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

Or you could just abstract this into a `clearfix` class which you apply here and anywhere else needed. See this: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

You can change your element style by applying css() function to your element once the effect is done. like:

> $(divId).css("background-color", "#ffe");
>   $(divId).css("border-left", "5px solid #ccc");

or

> document.getElementById('divId').style.-moz-box-shadow = 1px 1px 1px #000;